# Prevent uninstall in setup project with OnBeforeUninstall

Tags: c#, setup-project, uninstallation

I overrode `OnBeforeUninstall` to stop my application's setup project from uninstalling it  under certain circumstances, but it seems like it is just not being called and has no effect.

```
protected override void OnBeforeUninstall(IDictionary savedState)
{
    if (ApplicationIsBusy())
        throw new ApplicationException("Prevent uninstall while application busy.");
}
```

I am able to cancel uninstall by overriding the `Uninstall` method, but by then the setup project has already closed my application. How do I "fail" an uninstall attempt when my application is busy *before* the setup project tries to close it when it is running and interrupts my worker process?

Comment: Try to write a trace message in there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.writeline.aspx just to check if the method is called or not. You can check the trace messages with debugView  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx

Comment: Also from MSDN: "When overriding OnBeforeUninstall in a derived class, be sure to call the base class's OnBeforeUninstall method so that registered delegates receive the event."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before calling your custom code, call the base.OnBeforeUninstall(savedState) so that registered delegates receive the event thereby allowing your custom code to execute before the uninstall.

```
protected override void OnBeforeUninstall(IDictionary savedState)
{
    // Add this
    base.OnBeforeUninstall(savedState);

    if (ApplicationIsBusy())
        throw new ApplicationException("Prevent uninstall while application busy.");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that in the setup project you chose the custom action for uninstalling, that s probably your case.